# Unable to edit answer in review (audit)

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I was trying to edit an answer in review. When I tried, it said the answer was deleted. When I clicked "No Action Needed" thinking the OP deleted their answer, I got warned that I did not pass the audit. I feel this failure is unfair.

Comment: That warning was still part of the test, to see what you would do next.  You raised the problem here, which was the correct response, so you did actually pass the test.  Now that audit is complete. :-)

Comment: Unless you continuously fail, a singular failure, isn't that important.  The reason you failed is because the answer wasn't a "no action" answer.

Comment: Which is why I clicked on edit (to take action). There was no answer to edit, I assumed it was deleted as the system message stated, and pressed no action. You're saying I should have skipped? No action seems like a valid response to me.

Comment: If the answer was deleted then you would have been safe to skip it.  Why a deleted question was in the audit I cannot explain that but I just know the proper action wasn't "no action"

Comment: Why is no action not a valid action in that situation? If the question is deleted, why would I skip it make someone else review the post?

Comment: Many of the audit "bad" examples are already deleted posts.

Comment: I ran into the same problem - failing a review audit because I couldn't edit a deleted post.

Answer (score 2):

These audits, and tests for humans actually reviewing and observing all aspects of the reviewed items, are done by code (a machine, a program)  There is no human analising your responce to them, it is therefore fallable.

It still accomplishes the job of keeping humans on thier toes, and not blind acceptance.  If you failed to provide the correct responce the machine expects, welcome to the club. There are a few other ways in the audits you can get trapped for no good reason. The system for the most part still works.

Unfair ?  what does a machine know about fair :-)  It would be really unfair if a few of these knocked out your reputation, or sullied your name, or stop you from being able to function on the site.  Missing a few of these does nothing, you truely would have to be malicious, or not reading, or not paying any attention, or having a machine do it, for it to effect you in the short or long term.

Find below your membership card to the "Failed an Audit by Trying Too Hard" club.

Comment: As the club is certainly not a virtual one the card should neither be purely imaginary :-)