# Again: Failed Review Audit

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

I again have found a "late answer" review audit that I think is judged not entirely correct:
[This answer](https://superuser.com/review/first-answers/1104762) suggests to use a permanent marker to colour over an LED light on a monitor, while the author of the question already said that he wants to avoid to use tape, thus implying that he searches for a software based solution. Why is selecting "Share Feedback" wrong then?

Comment: https://meta.superuser.com/a/8971/19943

Comment: These tests are automatically generated and we have no control over them, they expect particular responses and actions **based on the review queue**. If you are making a comment on the contents of the answer beyond the intent of that particular review queue (i.e. how useful a late answer might be - is it a "good" or "bad" answer) then you might want to look at the question and other answers for a more complete view of the context.

Comment: Observation: HNQ QAs quite often encode... questionable audit outcomes